# `route get` for ipv6

Tags: network

How do I find the route for a specific IPv6 address?

For IPv4 I can do:

```
$ route -n get 1.1.1.1
   route to: 1.1.1.1
destination: 1.1.1.1
  interface: utun1
      flags: <UP,HOST,DONE,WASCLONED,IFSCOPE,IFREF>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1420         0
```

But for IPv6:

```
$ route -n get 2606:4700:4700::1111
route: bad address: 2606:4700:4700::1111
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, the answer is

```
route -n get -inet6 2606:4700:4700::1111
```

I find this syntax extremely cryptic and, the worst part, it is impossible to figure out from the help output and even understanding this after reading the man page is tricky.